# Don't close Option Menu when a menu item is pressed

Tags: android

For an options menu, I have 5 buttons, and would like the menu to stay present if one specific button is pressed. How may this be accomplished. Thanks!

Looking at the Android docs, I see there is a relevant constant FLAG_PERFORM_NO_CLOSE, but I am not sure how to apply it.

Comment: I think FLAG_PERFORM_NO_CLOSE is for shortcuts. e.g you have set 'A' as a shortcut for a menu item, when you press 'A' if the menu related functionality should be run but the menu bar should not be closed, then you will have to set this flag to performshortcut

Comment: Please move this item out of the options menu into your action bar or your main activity UI.

Comment: @CommonsWare: can the item still be present in the options menu if I recode it as you described?

Comment: No, because IMHO it should not be in the options menu in the first place.

Comment: Can I hack it so that that when button pressed, the menu will be seamlessly pulled up again without the animation?

Comment: You should make a Footer View or Navigation Bar sort of view for your app.
You can make it visible on the click of the "default menu" button also.

Comment: @CommonsWare I wish there was an answer to this. This is also the behavior in android's PopupMenu.